# How to determine that my cron job is done running?

Tags: linux, cron

I have two cron jobs. These jobs execute python scripts. I need to determine whether my job has completed its execution.

How can I programmatically find out about the completed cron jobs?

Comment: Do your jobs output anything? Return an exit code?

Comment: My python script writes something on the console. So, I guess cron job should print it too

Comment: Yup. :} ... is cron set to email results of jobs to any given account? Which user are you running them as?  And check /var/log/syslog (or the equivalent of **your** distro of choice) for cron entries ... :}

Comment: When job is finished, I get a mail here: /var/mail/jrambo

Comment: Sweet - you just answered your own question mate :}. You just need to parse your email ;}

Answer (score 1):

Or, as an alternative approach to what we discussed/found in the comments above ... a cron-tab entry modification in the spirit of:

```
X Y * * * /path/to/script1.py && /bin/date '+%Y%m%d%H%M script one ran' >> /home/jrambo/script1.log
X Y * * * /path/to/script2.py && /bin/date '+%Y%m%d%H%M script two ran' >> /home/jrambo/script2.log
```

Comment: You could also append something like `|| /bin/date ... script one failed >> ...`, or just echo the value of `$?`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: great suggestions. I'll leave that to John to decide - he wasn't too specific in his request :}